# How to use POST method to list data in RA

Tags: react-admin

I have tried to use ra-jsonapi-client to make POST call to my api and  list retrieved data. Is it possible? My code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';



import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';

const dataProviders = [
  { dataProvider: jsonapiClient('http://my.api.com:1234'), resources: ['get_info'] }]

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProviders}>
        <Resource name="get_info" list={ListGuesser} />
    </Admin>
);


export default App;
```

I know how to pass resource to dataprovider, but I can't figure out how to pass data and type in Resource. Is it possible or I need to write my own dataprovider?
I am pretty new to RA.
Thank you

Comment: you need to write your own data provider

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own [custom data provider](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/b280ed23f92ada71ae6b47a551239bd6bf314016/docs/DataProviders.md).  A data provider abstracts the details of your API away from react-admin.
React admin doesn't care what you need to do to get data from your API.